# Given a decimal time value, how could I round that to an interval?

Tags: php, time, decimal

For example, given the decimal value 5.66, representing 5 hours and 39 minutes, how would I round this number to 5 hours and 45 minutes (the nearest 15 minute interval), aka 5.75.

Similarly, if I had 5 hours and 36 minutes, or 5.6, this is closer to 5:30 than 5:45, so I'd want to get 5.5 out of it.

Trying to write this in PHP.

```
function round_decimal_time($time, $interval=15){
  // Split up decimal time
  $hours = (int) $time;
  $minutes = $time - $hours;

  // Convert base 10 minutes to base 60 minutes
  $b60_m = $minutes * 60;

  // Round base 60 minutes to nearest interval... (15 minutes by default)
  // DONT KNOW HOW TO DO THIS PART

  // If greater than or equal to 60, go up an hour
  if($b60_m >= 60){
      $hours += 1;
      $minutes = 0;
  } else {
    // Otherwise, convert b60 minutes back into b10
    $time = $hours + ($b60_m / 60);
  }

  return $time;
}
```

And again, some examples of what I'm trying to do.

```
Input: 5.66 (5:39 duration)
Output: 5.75

Input: 5.6 (5:36 duration)
Output: 5.50

Input: 5.05 (5:03 duration)
Output: 5.00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rounding to `'nearest number $X'` is done by:

```
 round($number/$X)*$X;
```

So, after (0.66 * 60 = 39.6):

```
 round(39.6/15)*15=45
```

You can use `ceil` and `floor` in a similar manner if you always want to round down or up.

Your total function would be:

```
 round_decimal_time($time,$round=15){
     return (round($time * 60 / $round) * $round) / 60;
 }
```

Comment: THe function isn't correct when $round > 60 b.t.w., Ill post a new one in a minute...

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = 5.66;
var_dump(round($a / 0.25) * 0.25);
```

And such approach is true for any rounding.

For example: if you had 7 and wanted to round to nearest number that is divided to 5 (5, 10, 15, 20, etc) you could do:

```
round(7 / 5) * 5
```

Answer (score 0):

To round anything to the nearest `x`, divide by `x`, round to the nearest integer, then multiply by `x`.